# Is there a way to limit SQL Server Developer Edition to features found in more restrictive versions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Essentially, we're developing for mostly SQL Server Web Edition for some databases and SQL Server  Standard Edition for others. We'd like to prevent the possibility of introducing a feature such as `vardecimal` in development if it won't be supported in the staging (and consequently production) versions.

Ideally there would be an option similar to compatibility level.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no such feature available, to my knowledge. You'll have to handle this by informing the developer about what features **not** to use, and by doing your own internal testing on the actual target platforms.

Comment: [Probably not something SQL Server will ever do, but may find its way into SSDT someday](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/496380/enable-sql-developer-edition-to-target-specific-sql-version).

Comment: No.  I ran into this when the production servers were "Standard".  I started using things that wouldn't work on production!  to my knowledge, DEV edition IS Enterprise edition.....but with different licensing issues (of course).........

Comment: Got it.  I think our strategy for now will be to use Sql Express locally to greatly limit our capabilities, and Developer in the staging environment.  Replication and advanced edition features can be implemented there.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature from Microsoft, but [Kimble Group](http://www.kimballgroup.com/) strongly advise in their [The Microsoft Data Warehouse Toolkit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470640383) to push the code through test or UAT environments (hopefully through continuous integration) where the version/edition would match the production. That of course relies on the assumption that most often this is the deployment strategy anyway.